# How can a name in an INI file be updated using a one-liner?

Tags: regex, perl, replace, ini

Replace value in a specific section of an INI file using Perl one-liner regex command?

I want to replace the "Margin Top" value of 1 to 0. The section must be "[Pagebar Button Skin]".

After I tried "(\[Pagebar Button Skin\].+?Margin Top\s+?=\s+?)(1)" with global and dotall in RegExr, I was able to replace the value with 0 using "$10" or "$1 0".

Unfortunately, it doesn't work when I run my command:

```
perl.exe -i.bak -pe "s/(\[Pagebar Button Skin\].+?Margin Top\s+?=\s+?)(1)/$1 0/g" test.txt
```

Here is the "[Pagebar Button Skin]" section in my test.txt file:

```
[Pagebar Button Skin]
Type                        = BoxStretch
Tile Center                 = pagebar/top/inactive.png
StretchBorder               = 12
Margin Top                  = 1
Margin Right                = -5
Margin Left                 = -5
Margin Bottom               = 0
Padding Left                = 12
Padding Top                 = 5
Padding Right               = 9
Padding Bottom              = 6
Spacing                     = 3
Text Color                  = #111111
```

**EDIT:**

I had to create a Perl script in order to get the regex to work. Maybe Perl doesn't like my Windows environment.

Command:

```
perl.exe skin.pl skin.ini
```

skin.pl:

```
$/ = undef; # Setting $/ to undef causes <FILE> to read the whole file into a single string.

# Store filename from argument
my $filename = shift;

# Open the file as read only and then store the file text into a string.
open(FILE, "<", $filename) || die "Could not open $filename\n";
my $text = <FILE>;
close(FILE);

# Re-open the file as writable and then overwrite it with the replaced text.
open(FILE, "+>", $filename) || die "Could not open $filename\n";
$text =~ s/(\[Pagebar\s+?Button\s+?Skin\].+?Margin\s+?Top\s+?=\s+?)(1)/${1}0/sg;
#print $text; # Print the text to screen
print {FILE} $text; # Print the text to the file
close(FILE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ini files are usually in paragraph mode you can try:

```
perl -p00 -e '/Pagebar Button Skin/ && s/(Margin Top.*=)\s*\d/$1 0/' file.ini
```

Output:

```
[Pagebar Button Skin]
Type                        = BoxStretch
Tile Center                 = pagebar/top/inactive.png
StretchBorder               = 12
Margin Top                  = 0
Margin Right                = -5
Margin Left                 = -5
Margin Bottom               = 0
Padding Left                = 12
Padding Top                 = 5
Padding Right               = 9
Padding Bottom              = 6
Spacing                     = 3
Text Color                  = #111111
```

Once you are satisfied with the results add -i.bak to one-liner

Comment: It works! This one answers the question! I just had to use double quotation marks instead of single: "Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1."

Answer (score 4):

Use a specialised module like [`Config::Tiny`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Config%3a%3aTiny) for parsing configuration files. A one-liner using it:

```
perl -MConfig::Tiny -we '$file = shift; $config = Config::Tiny->read($file); $config->{"Pagebar Button Skin"}->{"Margin Top"} = 0; $config->write($file)' test.txt
```

Comment: This will work. However, Config::Tiny will remove whitespace after writing the file, which may be undesirable. I had to create a Perl script in order to get the regex to work. Maybe Perl doesn't like my Windows environment.

Comment: _[XP1](http://stackoverflow.com/users/412486/xp1)_: Why do you want whitespace to persist? As far as I know, INI script parsers should ignore whitespace between `name` and `value`.

Comment: Yes, the parser would ignore the whitespace, but I just don't want to change the file too much because with a lot of whitespace removed, the file would look very different and would be more difficult to compare.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do it with a regex. Use a module. CPAN has [Config::INI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Config%3a%3aINI) and [Config::IniFiles](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Config%3a%3aIniFiles).

Comment: I won't be able to use the module in a one-line command. Is that correct?

Comment: XP1: You can use the `-M` or `-m` switch to `use` the module in a one-liner. See [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the line

```
perl -pe 'if (/^\s*\[Pagebar Button Skin\]/../^\s*\[/) { s/(Margin\s+Top\s*=\s*)1/${1}0/ }'
```

This will apply the substitution only between the start of the Pagebar section, and the next section. Also, you can use some INI module, read the file into perl as structure, change what you want and write it out. Depends on what better suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that I could do "${1}0" with the curly brackets. By the way, is your line getting cut off?

Comment: Corrected, dunno why it was cut off.